# Grouping by column inside condition

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate, apply

data frame

```
url

www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=66156587#76930014
www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=66156587#74975814
www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=66156587#77138214
www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=1527017600#72961607
www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=23195791#74343178
```

I cut the original dataframe

anyway I want to group by dataframe url no. except #

for example

```
          url  sum    

No=23195791      5
No=1527017600    3
```

I used code like this

```
ss1<-aggregate(ss11$buzz수, 
by=list(ss11$URL=="www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=%"), FUN=sum)
```

it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

How about something like,

```
res <- unlist(lapply(ss11$url,FUN = function(x) strsplit(strsplit(x,"#")[[1]],"No=")[[2]]))
```

to get a vector of parsed item numbers. After that `table(res)` will happily do the counting for you.